# Mesushelach, Benyamin and Mar Cheshvan

Tags: sources-mekorot, months

I read in a sefer (The Wisdom in the Hebrew Months volume 2 by Zvi Ryzman) which cited the Yalkut Shimoni as stating the following:

• Mesushelach, who was a perfect tzaddik, died on 11 Cheshvan, one week before the flood began.

• Benyamin was born on 11 Cheshvan and died 115 years later.

• HaKadosh Baruch Hu will pay back in Mar Cheshvan' [for not having inaugurated the Mishkan in that month].

Does anyone where the Yalkut Shimoni says this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yalkut Shimoni, Melakhim I, 184:

> א"ר חנינא בכ"ה בכסליו נגמר מלאכת המשכן ועשה מקופל עד אחד בניסן, כמו
>   שכתוב ביום החדש הראשון באחד לחדש תקים את משכן, והיו ישראל ממלמלין על
>   משה לומר למה לא הוקם מיד שמא דופי אירע בו והקב"ה חשב לערב שמחת המשכן
>   בחדש שנולד בו יצחק דכתיב לושי ועשי עוגות ואמרו לו שוב אשוב אליך, ומעתה
>   הפסיד כסלו שנגמרה בו המלאכה אמר הקב"ה עלי לשלם, מה שלם לו הקב"ה חנוכת
>   חשמונאי, **וכן מרחשון עתיד הקב"ה לשלם לו**

Yalkut Shimoni, Parashat Shemot:

> וימת יוסף וכל אחיו [א, ו] ראובן נולד בי"ד בכסליו מת בן קנ"ה שנים.
>   שמעון נולד בכ"ח בטבת ומת בן ק"כ שנה. לוי נולד בי"ו בניסן ומת בן קל"ז
>   שנים. יהודה נולד בט"ו בסיון ומת בן קי"ט שנים. דן בט' באלול ומת קכ"ה
>   שנה. נפתלי נולד בה' בתשרי ומת בן קל"ג שנה. גד בי' במרחשון ומת בן קכ"ה
>   שנים. אשר בכ' בשבט ומת בן קכ"ג שנים. יששכר נולד בי' באב ומת בן קכ"ב
>   שנים. זבולון בז' בתשרי ומת בן ק"י שנה. **בנימין נולד בי"א במרחשון** ומת בן
>   קט"ו שנים. באייר ושבט לא נולדו נשתייר לאפרים ומנשה:

Yalkut Shimoni, Parashat Noach:

> ויהי לשבעת הימים [ז, י] אמר רבא אלו ימי אבלו של מתושלח הצדיק ללמדך
>   שהספדן של צדיקים מעכב את הפורענות

The pasuk (Bereishit 7:11) says that the mabul began on the 17th day of the 2nd month, which one opinion identifies as Marcheshvan. This is the 7th day following the 11th of Marcheshvan.